# How to search keyword within blob?

Tags: git

How to get the commit where src/blob included `<keyword>`?

For example a **A()** already renamed to **B()**, so it cannot reserchable from working path. But I want to know which commit of this change came with.

**git log** or **git blame** seems not possible to get my question

Comment: You aren't asking for "commit where file included <word>" but rather for commit where "<word> changed" (in some particular file). That's because every commit has a full snapshot of every file, so there are probably very many commits where the word was included. As such, you probably want `git log -S`, which looks for diffs in which the number-of-occurrences of some text changed.

Comment: If you really *do* want what you've asked for with your title (but not with your example), consider `git grep`, which can search files within specified commits.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way by just

> git log --all -p  path | grep keyword.

it is working for me. Thanks